# Finding different items in 2 list vb.net

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, collections

I have 2 lists, collection type is up to me, it can be arraylist or hashtable etc.  Both lists   consist guid's.  I need to find the items of List-1 which doesnt exists in List-2.

Both **lists** can be containing **1 million** items.

I used hashtable approach but it is slow.

Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: from where are your lists coming from ? if coming from a database, it may be easier/quicker to filter there.

Comment: Neither of the collection types you mentioned should be used, they are both considered deprecated. You should use generic collections instead (in `Systems.Collections.Generic`). Do not use `ArrayList` or `Hashtable`.

Comment: you might not maintain a list of 1 million items, you might use consume list items, abandon that, and then reuse the list...

Comment: yes the lists are coming from database, but unfortunately from different mysql connections (different hosts), so i cant use 'not in' query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Hashset(of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and use the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method.  This will return all the items that are in hashset one but not in hashset two.

```
    Dim numbers1() As new HashSet(of Double)({2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5})
    Dim numbers2() As new hashset(of Double)({2.2})

    Dim onlyInFirstSet As IEnumerable(Of Double) = numbers1.Except(numbers2)

    ' This code produces the following output: 
    ' 
    ' 2 
    ' 2.1 
    ' 2.3 
    ' 2.4 
    ' 2.5
```

Comment: HashSets are to my knowledge by far the fastest way to do set based comparisons.  Your main performance drag is going to come from using GUID.  Long/Int ect are far faster.